# Developing hidden onion servers

Tags: webserver, server, tor

I was wondering which language is best to build a .onion website (PHP, Python, ...). Which language is more secure and which frameworks are more secure?

Is it a good idea to use CSS (Cascading Style Sheets)? Most .onion websites I've seen are written in HTML

Is true that HTTP server language and web framework has at one point had a vulnerability that exposes configuration or environment variables? If yes, how does that happen and how to avoid this problem?

Comment: Your question about languages does not have a definitive answer. The most insecure part of coding is the programmer. Your second question shows that you do not understand CSS. Please read up on how CSS works. Your last question does not relate to the others and does not matter what happened in the past, only what is vulnerable now.

Comment: I'm closing this because your only question that could be answerable is "which language is more secure?" There are answers to that question on this site.